How to run GHub Macro for Logitech G513?
I have a Logitech G513 Keyboard. I have installed the G Hub software.
Within G Hub, my keyboard is discovered and for example I can configure the RGB lightning just fine.
Now I want to create a basic macro, e.g. one that just inputs my user name k0pernikus. I can create the macro, I defined it as text, it shows up in the list of macros, yet how do I run it?
I cannot seem to find a way to add a keybinding for it.
Are macros even supported, as some other Logitech keyboards have Gx-keys, as in G1, G2, G3, etc. up to G5. Are those a requirement for running macros?

Update: While writing this question, I realized I could drag and drop my Macro on the F-keys, F1 to F12, within the G Hub software.
While this works it completely hijacks the F-key in question. I want to be able to use it, all its functionality, and rather have my macro bind somewhere custom.
I thought I could do something like fn + k to run my macro.



Appearantly this is long time known issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/LogitechG/comments/bern5y/question_is_it_possible_to_reassign_any_key_on
